Result of Trained Net Is Much Worse than Last Result from the Monitor
I try to use GAN to generate handwriting "2".
I noticed there is a complete example in the documentation of NetGANOperator. So I first tried the code from the documentation.
However, surprisingly, the monitoring function gives much better results than the final trained net.
The left picture is the last picture given by the monitoring function during training, and the right picture is the result given by the net after training is completed.


This is very strange.
Below is my code, which is almost exactly as in the documentation.
Clear["`*"]
trainingData = ResourceData["MNIST", "TrainingData"];
trainingData2 = Keys[Select[Association[trainingData], # == 2 &]];
convolutionBlock[args___] := 
  NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[args], NormalizationLayer[], 
    ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], DropoutLayer[0.4]}];
discriminator = 
 NetFlatten@
  NetChain[{convolutionBlock[64, {4, 4}, "Stride" -> {2, 2}], 
    convolutionBlock[64, {4, 4}, "Stride" -> {2, 2}], LinearLayer[{}],
     LogisticSigmoid}, 
   "Input" -> 
    NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale", "MeanImage" -> 0.5, 
      "VarianceImage" -> 0.5^2}]]
deconvolutionBlock[args___] := 
  NetChain[{DeconvolutionLayer[args], NormalizationLayer[], 
    ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], DropoutLayer[0.4]}];
generator = NetFlatten@NetChain[{
        {128, 7, 7}, NormalizationLayer[], ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], 
    DropoutLayer[0.4],
        deconvolutionBlock[64, {4, 4}, "Stride" -> {2, 2}],
        deconvolutionBlock[32, {4, 4}, "Stride" -> {2, 2}],
        ConvolutionLayer[1, {7, 7}], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh]
    }, "Input" -> 100, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[NetExtract[discriminator, "Input"]]]
getRandomLatent[batchSize_] := 
 Map[NumericArray[#, "Real32"] &, 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {batchSize, 100}]]
datagen = 
  Function[<|"Sample" -> RandomSample[trainingData2, #BatchSize], 
    "Latent" -> getRandomLatent[#BatchSize]|>];
showGeneratedDigits[net_] := ImageCollage[
   net[["Generator"]][getRandomLatent[7*7]], ImagePadding -> 1];
monitoring = "";
Dynamic[monitoring]
trained = NetTrain[NetGANOperator[{generator, discriminator}],
  {datagen, "RoundLength" -> Length[trainingData2]},
  TrainingUpdateSchedule -> {"Discriminator", "Generator"},
  TrainingProgressFunction -> {Function[
     monitoring = showGeneratedDigits[#Net]], 
    "Interval" -> Quantity [1, "Round"]},
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 100, TargetDevice -> "GPU"
  ]
showGeneratedDigits[trained]


By default, NetTrain implements early stopping (returns the model that has the lowest validation set loss, not necessarily the final model) if you provide a validation set. May be worth a shot to avoid overfitting... Beyond that loss function measurements on GANS are somewhat qualitative

@Joshua Schrier Your comment gave me the hint and I set up TrainingProgressCheckpointing . The last saved file did work out well.  I looked at the property "BestValidationRound", it was only 8. However my results do not seem to have the property "FinalNet"...
